# How to respond to disastrous workplace while looking for a new job?

Tags: quitting

I’ve just started job hunting, but even if I should find something quickly, it’s still going to be a matter of several weeks before I leave and it could certainly be more. How should I respond to my boss (the owner) and my manager in the meantime?

I’m planning to leave because my work has become chaotic. We’re barely keeping our heads above water. My boss doesn’t see this, however, and no matter how many prompts/warnings we give he refuses to see it. He’ll fixate on one problem and then our manager (after stress from him) will use very bullying language about my team and concentrate on that one problem. Which generally can’t be resolved because we are under staffed, have no working schedule for a massive workload etc. We have also reminded her multiple times about issues (on paper and in meetings) to no avail.

Basically, I don’t think my boss will change. I’ve known him for years and things have been steadily going downhill. I think the manager is so stressed out that in the context of this job she will never change either.

So should I keep raising issues and pointing stuff out, or should I just do my work in the time allotted and go home? Should I do bits of overtime because I know it will help other staff members with their overwhelming workload, or should I not bother? I feel like all my concerns etc are doing is taking up air space since they’re never actioned on or even given a straight answer. What would be the best way to handle this given that I want to be professional but don’t want extra stress to no gains?

Comment: Unclear to me what you mean with "boss" and "manager".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **I want to be professional** but don’t want extra stress to no gains

Professionalism - Sounds like you have done your best to notify them of the problems.

> So should I keep raising issues and pointing stuff out

You said they haven't "[acted] on or even given a straight answer" to your previous suggestions/complaints.  Sounds like a good time to stop suggesting and stop complaining (including to your co-workers).

> Should I do bits of overtime because I know it will help other staff members

Sounds like you are saying that (even if you could fix the whole problem by increasing your hours *with no pay*) this would not solve the problem... so, no you shouldn't.

> I want to be professional but **don’t want extra stress to no gains**
>
> should I just do my work in the time allotted and go home?

Yes.
And you should do it well enough that they miss you when you're gone.

Answer (score 5):

You do your best no matter the circumstances up until you exit on your final shift. To do otherwise would be unprofessional and (especially if you haven't procured a new job yet) could also lead to you no longer having a job. Shrugging your shoulders and saying to yourself: "Whatever, I don't care what happens I'm out the second I can." has a way of backfiring. I've seen it many times before. Get the other job before you check out.

Answer (score 3):

You are on your way out. The company looks like they are going down, and whatever you do won’t change it. You worked for a long time, trying to improve things, and nobody listened. So don’t worry about the company.

Do your best to find a good job. And do enough at your company to not get into trouble. That’s it.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would just act normal until I get a concrete offer, then give them two weeks notice. If you've already decided in your head it's time to go, don't torture yourself. I've stayed at places 2 years longer than I should have twice. It's easy to get complacent and just deal, but it's probably bad for your career because you'll get burned out.

Answer (score 0):

## Documentation. Ask for advice from experts on how.

In all cases where you have dysfunction in a workplace — no matter if it is an isolated case or if it is endemic to the workplace — **documentation** is always the start of the solution.

This is often because — as you have already concluded in your case — that verbal communication has broken down. Your sentiments are not getting through. The information you are trying to convey leaks out into nothingness and evaporates.

Hence, you **document** the situation, because documentation is less prone to evaporate.

What and how to document depends on your particular situation. I cannot advice you there. What you should do is get in touch with people that are experts in helping people at dysfunctional workplaces, and remedying dysfunctional workplaces, which is to say:

- **Worker unions**
- **Workplace inspection authorities**

They can help you make a graceful exit and give you advice on how to capture your experience so that you can hand that over to your soon-to-be-ex employer in a meaningful manner.

Comment: Two things - you can often document something verbal by sending an email saying that this is what you understand the boss wants done.  Second, if practical and legal, keep a copy of your documentation under your control, somewhere not at work or on a system they can lock you out of.